# React InstantSearch Dropdown RefinementList not Working: expected a string or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, algolia

I am trying to make use of [this guide](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-labs/tree/master/dropdown-refinement-list/react-instantsearch) to create a dropdown refinementlist instead of the default. I first created a `Dropdown.js` with contents form [here](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-labs/blob/master/dropdown-refinement-list/react-instantsearch/src/component/DropdownRefinementList.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connectRefinementList } from 'react-instantsearch/connectors';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const cx = label => `ais-DropdownRefinementList-${label}`;
/// Rest of the code from the above link follows
export default connectRefinementList(DropdownRefinementList);
```

I then import it into my `search.js` component, which builds my interface like so:

```
import { DropdownRefinementList} from "./Dropdown"
```

And use it like so:

```
<DropdownRefinementList attribute="major" />
```

This gives me the following error:

```
×
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `SearchGrid`.
```

`SearchGrid` is just my search component. The issue goes away when I remove `<DropdownRefinementList attribute="major" />`, so that has to be the problem.

Is there something wrong with my implementation? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `import DropdownRefinementList from "./Dropdown"`

This is because you're exporting default from your `Dropdown.js` file.

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Aman, so what is your export(or your solution) now? can you share?